# 'error processing archive ubuntudde-default-setting s_1.1.7-1_all.deb' when trying to install ubuntudde-dde on Xubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, dpkg, deepin-desktop-environment

I'm trying to install the Deepin desktop on my Xubuntu installation using the `ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable` repo. Most of the process went find except for one package: `ubuntudde-default-setting s_1.1.7-1_all.deb`, which returns the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntudde-default-settings_1.1.7-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/skel/.config/Trolltech.conf', which is also in package xubuntu-default-settings 20.04.4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntudde-default-settings_1.1.7-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried all the essential apt commands such as `apt --fix-broken install` and `apt -f install` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to request manual overwritting by using command below:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntudde-default-settings_1.1.7-1_all.deb
```

and then resume installation

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Works flawlessly, thank you.